# Copy files between two hosts

Tags: scp, remote, file-copy

How can I copy files between two hosts the first primary host is running Linux and the secondary host is running Windows.
I am looking for a correct command line to use it in terminal/Linux?

I tried

```
scp user1@remote1:/home/file user2@remote:/home/file
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: (s)FTP, Mounding drives, rcp, ... the list is quite long

Comment: WinSCP if you are running ssh server on Linux

Comment: no. From the name it is Windows software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, install and run the SSH daemon `sshd` (the package is `openssh-server` in most distributions). Then from Windows download and use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) to connect to the Linux machine and transfer your files in both directions.

Or - to do this the other way around - install the SSH server [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) on Windows, then from Linux run the command `scp user1@linuxbox:/home/user1/myfile user2@winbox:` (adapt as appropriate).

All these tools are available for free.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a SMB-share on your Windows host. Install smbclient on your Linux host (on Debian you can do it with `sudo apt-get install smbclient`). Connect to your SMB-share with:

```
smbclient //NETBIOS_NAME/RESOURCE -I IP.ADD.RE.SS -N
```

And finally download a file with:

```
get (filename)
```